# 24volt to 5volt pulse conversion without affecting frequency

Tags: opto-isolator

im a newbie . id really appreciate if you could help me out on this issue.

i have a 24v operated pulse generator that i want fed into the arduino working at 5v. how do i change the voltage level without changing the frequency of the pulses.

These pulses are from an open collector output of 24VDC .maximum frequency of 5khz.
will a voltage divider work??or is optocoupler recommended ?

thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Why would the frequency change?

Comment: the rate of the pulses change according to the flow of the liquid under considerations. hence the frequency changes.

Comment: my main question is will a voltage divider affect the pulses because our primary aim is to count pulses.

Comment: 1. The rate of flow of the liquid has nothing to do with it. Consider: If you inject a 1kHz pulse train into the end of a piece of coax with a velocity factor of 0.6, the train will exit the coax as a 1kHz pulse train, and if you inject it into a piece of twin-lead with a velocity factor of 0.9 it'll still come out the other end as a 1kHz pulse train. 2. The voltage divider will only affect the amplitude of the pulse train and the crispness of the edges; the frequency in and out will remain identical.

Answer (score 1):

If the output is open collector, all you need to do is provide a pullup to 5 volts instead of 24 volts. Open collector means the output device only pulls low, not high, so the pullup resistor determines the high voltage.

If you can't do that for some reason, you can build a voltage divider using the existing pullup resistor and one to ground, calculated to output 5 volts with 24 volts input. This will affect anything else attempting to measure the same signal, however.

Comment: thank you @ nickjohnson. will an optcoupler be necessary in this case??

Comment: @summer93 Only if you need to isolate the two circuits - for instance because they have different ground potentials, or because one side may be subject to surges or spikes you want to protect the other from

Comment: the pulses are generated from an isolating switching amplifier and have to be fed to an arduino pin to measure the number of pulses. the frequency of the pulses changes depending on the sensor value.   can you please help out in deciding whether to use an optocoupler for this purpore or a voltage divider. thanks in advance

Comment: @summer93 I don't know enough about your system to answer that. Like I said, it depends on whether you need the ground of your Arduino and the ground of the device you're reading pulses from to be separate.

Comment: my main query is will a voltage divider affect the pulses because my primary aim is to count pulses. my basic question is does a voltage divider work just as well for pulses as it does for a dc level.

Comment: @summer93 Affect them how? It will simply divide the voltage.